# M2M relationship in Django and intermediate table contain extra field

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have to models with M2M relation which are clinic and Doctor but the third custom intermediate table with additional field shift.

```
class ClinicHospital(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    address = models.TextField()
    contact = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    lat = models.FloatField()
    lon = models.FloatField()

class Doctor(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    speciality = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length = 12)
    speciality = models.ForeignKey(Speciality, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    clinic_hospital = models.ManyToManyField(ClinicHospital, through='DoctorHospital')
```

intermediate table is

```
class DoctorHospital(models.Model):
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(ClinicHospital, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shift = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
```

**Problem**
First, DoctorHospital table is not shown/created in DB.
Second, when I save **Clinic** it does but **Doctor** does not save, it returns error doctorhospital is not exist.

[image]

this error view show when save **Doctor**

Comment: Can you show the view where you create the relation?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you mean ER relation?

Comment: No, exactly what are you doing to "trigger" that error.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it worked. it was my stupidity